# Save download in generated directory in Python on Windows OS

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I am currently trying to automate downloading images from the internet. My URL is similar to the below using Python 2.7:-

http://www.myphotos.com/user/album/photoID.jpg

What I am looking to do is the following:

1. Use the `user` part as a directory name.
2. Use the `album` part as a subdirectory name.
3. Save the image in the respective subdirectory.

I can download the images no problem into the root directory however when I try and apply the below I get an error. Here's my code:-

```
import os
import urllib

# this is the URL for the image
thumbnail =  "http://www.myphotos.com/user/album/photoID.jpg"

# Put the images in the directory for user and album
user = thumbnail.split('/')[3]
album = thumbnail.split('/')[4]
image_dir_location = "/" + user + "/" + album
if not os.path.exists(image_dir_location):
    os.makedirs(image_dir_location)
urllib.urlretrieve(thumbnail, image_dir_location + thumbnail.split('/')[6])
```

When I run this script, it doesn't seem to download any files at all nor generate the directories. Bizarrely though, it doesn't generate any error neither.

Comment: Your `image_dir_location` is an absolute path.  You should leave out the leading `/`.  Also, your directory creating strategy is brittle.  Prefer using `os.makedirs(… , exists_ok=True)` and get rid of the check.

Comment: Your indices are also bogus.  I think it would be easier to index from the end: `urlparts = url.split('/'); image = urlparts[-1]; album = urlparts[-2]; user = urlparts[-3];`  Note that I'm `split()`ting the string only once and am using more descriptive variable names.  You also might want to look into `os.path`.

Comment: Another problem is that you need to add a path separator between the `image_dir_location` and the `thumbnail.split('/')[6]` in the `urlretrieve()` call.